# Query Model and Join Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-associations

I wish to select all of the `QuizVersion` model information and the related `Quiz` model all in one line.

Below is what I have so far and It's not outputting any `Quiz` information, just `QuizVersion` information:

**Controller:**

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController

    def getquiz

        @myquiz = QuizVersion.joins(:Quiz).find([14,16])
    end

end
```

**Quiz Model:**

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "quizzes"
  set_primary_key "quiz_ID"
  has_many :QuizVersions, :primary_key => "quiz_version_id", :foreign_key => "quiz_version_id"
end
```

**QuizVersion Model:**

```
class QuizVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  set_primary_key "quiz_version_id"
  belongs_to :Quiz, :primary_key => "quiz_id", :foreign_key => "quiz_id"
end
```

Here's the resulting information:

```
---
- !ruby/object:QuizVersion
  attributes:
    quiz_version_id: 14
    quiz_id: 18
    quiz_name: Super Hero Quiz
    intro: Take this quiz to find out which super hero you are most like!
    email: ''
    activated: 0
    ip_address: 127.0.0.1
    public: 0
    quiz_type: ''
    created_time: 1347360590
- !ruby/object:QuizVersion
  attributes:
    quiz_version_id: 16
    quiz_id: 18
    quiz_name: Super Hero Quiz
    intro: Take this quiz to find out which super hero you are most like!
    email: ''
    activated: 0
    ip_address: 127.0.0.1
    public: 0
    quiz_type: ''
    created_time: 1347706841
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@myquiz = Quiz.includes(:QuizVersions).find([14,16])
```

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't pull through any QuizVersions information through.  Any ideas for why that could be?

Answer (score 0):

First off, usually associations are defined using lower case:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "quizzes"
  set_primary_key "quiz_ID"
  has_many :quiz_versions
end

class QuizVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  set_primary_key "quiz_version_id"
  belongs_to :quiz
end
```

With that you can then use:

```
QuizVersion.includes(:quiz).find([14,16])
```

Hope that helps

EDIT: I confess that I haven't ran this to double check however...

Comment: Or you could try `QuizVersion.where(id: [14,16]).joins(:quiz)`

Comment: This still just brings back only QuizVersion information.  Could it be something to do with my :foreign_key/:primary_key setups within my classes?  My quiz and quiz versions are related ON `quizzes.quiz_id` = `quiz_versions.quiz_id`

Comment: There is a chance this is because rails isn't adding the data into the object. If you call `quiz_version.quiz` after retrieving a record check the console to see if it executes another query

Comment: As you can tell, I'm a massive noob with this language.  I'm passing @myquiz so that I can use it in my view.  Please see the edit on my question for the current view.  Please can you show me how I would access the field 'url_id' from my quizzes table within the view?  I have tried `@myquiz.quiz_versions.url_id` and it returns a NoMethodError on quiz_versions.  Thanks

Comment: `@myquiz.quiz_versions.collect(&:url_id).join(", ")` because you have multiple quiz versions it will return an array so you either iterate similar to my example or you can select the latest: `@myquiz.quiz_versions.last.url_id`